# Creating an external Javascript file and linking in div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this script working as an external javascript file, can anyone give me a hand? Also it needs to be placed in a div tag within my webpage

```
var imgArray = new Array("Home Page/Images/Slideshow/bus-resize.jpg",
        "Home Page/Images/Slideshow/.jpg",
        "Home Page/Images/Slideshow/.jpg");
var imgCount = 0;
function startTime() {
if(imgCount == imgArray.length) {
    imgCount = 0;
}
document.getElementById("img2").src = imgArray[imgCount];
imgCount++;
setTimeout("startTime()", 5000);
```

}

Comment: What do you mean it needs to be in a div tag?  Do you mean the image needs to be in a div tag?

Comment: This question is completely unclear.  We cannot tell what you are asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: The above Javascript is for a slideshow-type object, for the sake of having a clean html document and so i don't have to repeat the script multiple times in my html doc (as i will be using it a number of times) i want to have it as an external javascript file. I have tried calling the js file within a div:

        <div id="body">
         <div class="slideshowleft"> 
             <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    
        </div>

Comment: I don't know your reasons, but to have an script inside a DOM object doesn't make any sense to me. The effect you want can be easily achieved by placing the script inside the header section, as in any normal HTML document, so unless you have very good reasons for doing what you describe, I don't see the point in complicating your life for free.

Comment: I am wanting to have 3 repeating slideshows in a line in the center of my page, regardless of screen size and each slideshow will show different pictures, as i am new to web design and programming, if someone has a better suggestion i would love to hear it, all this positioning is irritating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your code work all you need is this line in your HTML:

```
<imd id=img2></img><script>startTime();</script>
```

But please don't use this solution since it will make repeated requests, even for images that were already loaded, by changing the src attribute.

Instead use this that makes the same thing but instead of changing the src attribute it uses 3 elements and hides 2 of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/edFPA/3/

Js

```
var Each = function(array, callback){
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    callback.apply(array, [array[i], i, array]);
  }
};
var hideAll = function(elements) {
    Each(elements, function(img){
        img.className = 'hide';
    });
};
var flipImages = document.querySelectorAll('.images-flip img');
hideAll(flipImages);
var Counter = function(init, cb, t){ 
    this.start = function(){  
        init.call(this);
        this.loop();
    };
    this.callback = cb;
    this.loop = function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(this.loop.bind(this), t);
        this.callback.call(this);
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    };
    return this;
};
var flipArray = document.querySelectorAll('.images-flip');
Each(flipArray, function(flip){
    flip.counter = new Counter(function(){
        this.count = 0;
      },
      /*loop*/ function(){
        hideAll(flip.children);
        flip.children[this.count].className = '';
        this.count = (this.count+1) % flip.children.length;        
      }, 
    flip.dataset.time);
    flip.counter.start();
});
```

Html

```
<div class="images-flip" data-time="1000">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/apps-script/images/script-128.png">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/google-apps/images/manage.png">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/google-apps/images/apidownload128.gif">
</div>
<div class="images-flip" data-time="1500">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/_static/images/gplus-32.png">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/_static/images/android-32.png">
  <img src="https://developers.google.com/_static/images/chrome-32.png">
```

Css

```
.images-flip {
  position: relative; 
  width: 128px; height: 128px;
  float: left;
}
.images-flip img {
  position: absolute;
}
.images-flip img.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason i couldn't get your code to work, the images simply overlapped each other ???

Comment: I think the problem is with calling Javascript into the doc. Can you tell me why this wouldn't work? <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"> </script>

Comment: This must work, it must be something else. Can you put all your files in a zip and send me a link with dropbox?

Comment: Here's the link, i have made it the page as basic as possible to eliminate interference:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd2reft388z7nlo/slideshow.rar

Also, i need to say, your website background is nothing short of incredible. The South Park touch is funny too, i saw the mega-man pic and thought you might be interested in this, if you haven't already seen it:

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mightyno9/mighty-no-9?ref=live

Comment: Cool project ... really awsome thx 4 sharing. Your only problem is that your <script> tag should be in the end of the HTML <body> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppdl9q9xmpk0hzx/slideshow.zip . You could use a "onload" event listener instead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you know why i can't have 2 or more of these scripts running at the same time?

Comment: No problem, I updated the answer so you can create multiple <div> with class "images-flip" and use a "data-time" attribute to set, well, you guessed, TIME in miliseconds;

Comment: you could do it with CSS only ... will post it soon

Comment: There it goes http://jsfiddle.net/edFPA/5/ no JS needed but you need to worry about prefixes (or include prefixfree.js like I did)

Comment: Hi Rafael, sorry me again.

I finished my site, i began testing in other browsers, code checking etc, when i came across a problem with this in IE. IE doesn't accepts this code, would you have any idea how i could stop IE from running it? For example it's own css

Comment: IE is very complicated ... for each version you will get a different problem ... try solving them one at a time ... http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ ... and always use a fallback to a very simple version if the browser don't let you do the fancy stuff!

Comment: Using the developer tools in IE, i found that IE was having problems with the img.hide css, so i hid that from IE and that fixed it. Thanks for the link though.